# Remove duplicate columns only by their values

Tags: python, pandas

I just got an assignment which i got a lot of features (as columns) and records (as rows) in a csv file.

Cleaning the data using Python (including pandas):

```
A,B,C
1,1,1
0,0,0
1,0,1
```

1. I would like to delete all the duplicate columns with the same values and to remain only one of them. **A** and **B** will be the only column one to remain.
2. I would like to combine the columns that have high Pearson correlation with the target value, how can i do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to delete all the duplicate columns with the same values and to remain only one of them. `A` will be the only column one to remain.

You mean that's the only one among the `A` and `C` that's kept, right? (`B` doesn't duplicate anything.)

You can use `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

It works on rows, not columns, so I transpose before/after calling it.

> I would like to combine the columns that have high Pearson correlation with the target value, how can i do it?

You can do a loop matching all columns up and computing their correlation with `DataFrame.corr` or with `numpy.corrcoef`.

Comment: I tried to this but I got this on the transpose:
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00001208 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 35 in _prod
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2485 in prod
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3875 in loop
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3898 in loop
  ...

Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: @AdirSolo, there is something about your code or data that I don't know. Pastebin a full http://sscce.org/

Comment: @AdirSolo, (For the sample provided, it certainly should work -- https://bpaste.net/show/699e47f724e5 )